# Given line $e$ and plane $\alpha$, find all points $Q$ on $e$ such $d(Q, P)= d(Q, \alpha)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Can someone help me with this question and show my step by step process. I am unable to solve it. Thank you.

$P(4,2,5)$

The plane $\alpha$ is given by $2x+y-2z=2$

The line $e$ is given by $\dfrac{x-2}2 = \dfrac{y-1}5 = \dfrac{z+3}2$

Find all points $Q$ on $e$ such that the distance of $Q$ to $P$ is equal to the distance of $Q$ to $\alpha$.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: You will find that you get a more positive reception when you show your work. We don't ecpect you to solve it, but we do expect you to show that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Explicit part:
Note that the equation for $e$ is a parametrization.  Set it ${} = t$:
$$ \frac{x-2}{2} = \frac{y-1}{5} = \frac{z+3}{2} = t $$
so that $x = 2t+2$, $y = 5t+1$, and $z=2t-3$.

Now that you can write down explicit coordinates of points on $e$, how should you proceed?

Comment: plug in the x,y,z into the alpha equation and find t? Then substitute t with the value I got to find a point?

Comment: @Erum : Your question asks about distances.  How do you compute distances?  Do you compute distances by plugging points of one object into the equations defining other objects?

Comment: The distance from the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to the plane 
$ax + by + cz = d$ is $\dfrac{|ax_0+by_0+cz_0 - d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$.